possible compilation problems and strange behavior of the memory allocation in C
I have a program in C that gets a continued fractional representation.
It works fine, but shows an unpredictable behavior for some test cases (one of them is hard coded in program).
In one from five sequential executions or something similar (can fail on any), it attempts to allocate 20.0T of memory, as it shows in htop. I can't figure out what is wrong, since no warnings or errors are mentioned with the --fsanitize=address compilation flag.
Update 1:
The same kind of a problem appears even when a totally empty program (just main with return 0) compiled with same flags and executed.
Can some of compilation flags (or combination of them) be the root of the problem?
Text of the program itself:
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void iswap(int *source, int *dist) {
  int tmp = *source;
  *source = *dist;
  *dist = tmp;
}

int *get_frac_repr(int *a, int *b, int *depth, int *frac_repr) {
  int quotient, mod, numer, denom;

  numer = *a;
  denom = *b;
  assert(denom != 0);

  for (int i = 0;; i++) {
    quotient = numer / denom;
    mod = numer % denom;

    int *memory_check_pointer = realloc(frac_repr, (i + 1) * sizeof(int));
    if (!memory_check_pointer) {
      printf("Memory allocation failed");
      exit(1);
    } else {
      frac_repr = memory_check_pointer;
    }

    frac_repr[i] = quotient;

    if (mod == 0) {
      *depth = i + 1;
      break;
    } else {
      numer = mod;
      iswap(&numer, &denom);
    }
  }
  return frac_repr;
}
int main() {

  int a, b;
  int *depth = (int *)calloc(1, sizeof(int));
  int *frac_repr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));

#if 0
  int nitems = scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);

  if (nitems != 2 || b == 0) {
    printf("Invalid args. Expected any int a and int b != 0.");
    return 0;
  }
#else
  a = 246824;
  b = 135791;
#endif

  int *res = get_frac_repr(&a, &b, depth, frac_repr);

  for (int i = 0; i < *depth; i++) {
    printf("%d ", res[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");

  free(depth);
  free(res);

  return 0;
}

Makefile:
CC = gcc 
CFLAGS = -g -lc -lm -Wall -Werror -O0 -fsanitize=address -static-libasan
curr := sem_1/problem_cf

all: $(curr)

$(curr): src/$(curr).c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) src/$(curr).c -o build/$(curr)

OS info, used for execution:
Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS x86_64
